# Vue-js2 passing props into component is unexpectedly reactive

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

("vue": "^2.6.11"). I've been trying to get a component working on a Vue-js page, following various tutorials.
The outside component contains a reference to the inside component:

```
   <!--- loop to output individual questions here --->
   <question-box v-for = "question in qSection.questions" 
      :key="question.qid"
      :question="question"
   />
```

Now the inside component has a small form that displays parts of the question object, and allows altering them:
...

```
<td>
    {{ question.txt }}
    <div v-if="question.incf">
      <br/>
      <textarea rows="2" cols = "80" 
        v-model="question.cmt" placeholder = "Comments here"
        class="hideOnPrint"
      />
      <div class="print-only"> {{ question.cmt }} </div>
    </div>
  </td>
```

...
etc.
Now, from all the tutorials, I thought I would need
:question.sync="question" or such in the outer component,
and some kind of $emit(update: in the inner component.
But - I found to my surprise that the question data shows up fine in question-box, and when it is altered in the inner component, it gets altered as well in the outer component data this.qSection.questions. Can print from there, refile the overall form from there, etc., with the new values. I.e., works as is.
Is this a real feature, why is it happening, and can I rely on it? Thanks!

Comment: don't edit props (add a linter), instead pass/clone the prop to a new object in data and then edit that, once you finished editing, $emit back the value, then in the parent update the original

Comment: *Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child component will affect parent state.*  - [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone. That's what the docs all say. But why do I need to do all that when it works as it is now?

Comment: @MichalLevý. So that's okay to leave it this way?

Comment: misusing something is a choice

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I hear you. But this actually corresponds better to the normal programming paradigm of passing something to a subroutine. If you pass it by reference, both of them are working on the same object. Why is that misuse?

Comment: Separations of concerns, ill give you an example, you pass in a prop and use it in a input as a model, on change/input then it will update the parent then depending on the structure your app may rerender or you may not want the value to update until save is clicked etc, additionally, deeply nested values may lose reactivity, you should pass in a prop, make a copy to a local value in data emit it back to the parent,this fits in with vuex and if you do it right you won't get warnings in console and when using a linter like eslint it won't complain,in nuxt your app won't build if you mutate props

Comment: @MikeArrh Well lots of people is very strict about this and juggling with a lot of word like "separation of conserns" for example. I'v seen insane code that could be reduced by 80% just by using this "feature". If your component is called "XXXEditor" and receves an object as a prop, I see logical and practical that that component can and should modify the object passed in...

Comment: Thanks to you too!